# Can't Upgrade Mac Pro 2010, XCode and iOS SDK

Tags: mac, updates, ios, xcode, sdk

Per Apple's new distribution requirements I need XCode 11 and SDK 13 to release a new version of an app but to get those I need an iOS upgrade to 10.14 which doesn't exist! I'm told by Apple support that I am out of luck and the machine is not updateable any longer.  I have to toss the machine as a dev environment.  Any ideas how I can make this work?

I'm running a 13" Mac Mid-2010; High Sierra 10.13.6; XCode 10.1; NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB graphics card; 500 GB SSD; 4 GB Ram.  Its in top shape and plenty powerful enough to develop apps on.

I ran an update check and checked the iOS documentation. Everything is up to date and there is not any pending update for iOS. XCode has a pending update but it shows incompatible with the current OS version.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210190

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208898

Comment: There are enthusiasts dedicated to patching Mac OS to run on older Macs who have had some success. Which would seem to prove the lack of official support is a case of planned obsolescence as much as anything. Anyway, try searching around, there are articles such as this one https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/install-catalina-old-mac-3654960/.  Be aware that there are risks and you could end up with a non-working system. Anyway, I suspect someone will close this soon since running on hardware not officially sanctioned by Apple is considered off-topic

Comment: My research turned up that the new iOS makes use of the video card more than previous and the card in this machine isn’t capable.  Even though i don’t use or need more capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides 5 years' primary support for hardware, followed by 5 years' secondary support [full system updates initially, followed by & some security updates]. You've hit 10 years; your Mac is now officially End of Life; legacied. There is no official way to update your Mac any further. You can continue to use it, but it will no longer receive any updates.

Your choices now are either

1. New supported hardware,

or [with no guarantees anything will work as expected]

2. A hacked install.

This is not illegal, nor is it against licensing terms - you're running macOS on Apple hardware. The downside is things might just break, or fail to operate as expected.

dosdude1 is a well-known source of these 'forced' upgrades. They are 'safe' for any given definition of safe [ie they are definitely not malicious], but use at your own risk. They enable installation of newer macOS on unsupported hardware - including some tweaks for Metal2 graphics, which you don't have.

http://dosdude1.com/software.html

Caveat emptor.

Comment: I wonder if i can create a vmware or fusion vm and run the new OS in there or on a Win 7 machine.

Comment: It might be worth a try on Fusion. I wouldn't bother on Windows 7 as it's a) much harder to do & b) against licensing terms.